# SQL select values of each selected columns on separate rows

Tags: sql, select

I have a table with hundreds of rows and tens of W columns:

```
Column1 | Column2_W | Column3_W | ColumnX_W
  123   |     A     |     B     |    x
  223   |     A     |    NULL   |  NULL
```

How can i select it so that the output would be:

```
Column1 | W 
  123   | A
  123   | B
  123   | x
  223   | A
```

EDIT: I am well aware that i am working with a terrible DB "design". Unfortunately i can't change it. This question is actually part of a larger problem i was handed today. I will try the given ideas tomorrow

Comment: Suggest you look up unpivot. Hopefully you are doing this to take this data to a more normalized format as this is a terrible way to store data long term..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this article: [UNPIVOT: Normalizing data on the fly](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/04/23/unpivot.aspx)

Unforunately, you're going to be stuck hand typing the column names with any of the solutions you use. Here's a sample using `UNPIVOT` in SQL Server...

```
SELECT Column1, W
FROM YourTable
UNPIVOT (W for Column1 in (Column2_W, Column3_W /* and so on */)) AS W
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2_W
FROM table

UNION ALL

SELECT Column1, Column3_W
FROM table

UNION ALL

SELECT Column1, Column4_W
FROM table
....
ORDER BY Column1
```

Better option: redesign your database! This looks like a spreadsheet, not a relational database.

Comment: I know how this looks and i'm quite frustrated to work with such a database. Unfortunately there is nothing i can do about the DB design

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any UNPIVOT options...

```
SELECT
  Column1,
  CASE ColumnID WHEN 2 THEN Column2_W
                WHEN 3 THEN Column3_W
                ...
                WHEN X THEN ColumnX_W
  END AS Column2
FROM
  yourTable
CROSS JOIN
  (          SELECT 2 AS ColumnID
   UNION ALL SELECT 3
   ...
   UNION ALL SELECT X
  )
    AS UnPivot
```